# String to Hex without changing number, C++

Tags: c++, string, type-conversion, hex

While working on a project, I found myself wondering how to convert from string to hex. Not just converting from, let's say, the string "42" to hex 0x3432.

I'm curious how you would go about converting the string "0x42" to hex 0x42. As in, assume the string given is a valid hex number (I know that's a big assumption, but go with it...). I want to use that as a hex number, not as a string anymore. How would I go about doing that conversion?

This isn't something I'd do... I'm just more curious if and how it would be done, as I've never run into this type of problem until now.

*Using C and C++

Comment: `std::istringstream` + `std::hex` should do the job well.

Comment: `std::stoi`  is the easy way.  In C, the `strtoul` family can do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As this is just a matter of different representations of the same value, its IO streams that offer such "conversion":

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::stringstream ss{"0x42"};
    int x = 0;
    ss >> std::hex >> x;
    std::cout << x << "\n";
    std::cout << std::hex << x;
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/cP9EdPb9Y):

```
66
42
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "0x42";
    int i = std::stoi( s, nullptr, 16 );
    int j = strtoul( s.substr(2).c_str(), nullptr, 16 );
    std::cout << i << "," << j << "\n";
}
```

Note that `std::stoi` will handle the leading "0x".  `strtoul` is pickier.

Comment: In your answer, you wrote: `strtoul is pickier` -- Judging from the [documentation of that function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul), it seems to me that the function should reliably accept the `0x` prefix.

Comment: Since you are not `using namespace std;` (which is good), I believe you should write `std::strtoul` instead of `strtoul`. Also, you should `#include <cstdlib>`. Your code seems to work as is with gcc and clang, but unless I am mistaken, this is not guaranteed by the ISO C++ standard.

Comment: I agree with @AndreasWenzel: `strtoul` is just fine with the `0x` prefix. And if you use 0 as the base, it will use that prefix to automatically determine it is hexadecimal. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/ned5Y6eMe).

Comment: I like this answer better than the stringstream one, but the comments do need to be resolved first.